# Setting images in bindView (Cursor Adapter) how to differentiate between Uri that has image data and the the one that does not

Tags: android

I am trying to set images in my ListView in the bindView method of the cursor adapter, actually the whole data (relating to a contact) is pre-fetched in a database table. I query this table to fetch my image uri ( For every contact there is an image Uri regardless if there is an image or not). Now for those contacts which do not have an image I want to display a default image. However I tried with the following code, but my images are repeated in views which dont have images in Uri location by images which have data in Uri locations ( Other contacts images).

Following is my code:

```
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView1)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name")));
            ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView2)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("BirthDate")));
            ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView1)).setTypeface(tf);
            ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView2)).setTypeface(tf); 

            String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imageUri"));
            Uri IMAGE_URI = Uri.parse(image); 

            InputStream stream = Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), IMAGE_URI);
            if (stream == null) {
                ((ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.imageView1)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_01); 
            }
            if(stream != null){
                BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(stream);

                Bitmap my_btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
                ((ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(my_btmp);
            }



        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Another way to overcome this would be to query the contact directly, however I am unsure what effect it will have on memory and how slow the process will get for each row of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Thanks to [Techfist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1693725/techfist) for giving me a hint:

This statement is important:

```
IMAGE_URI= Uri.withAppendedPath(IMAGE_URI, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
```

And then finally in the bindView:

```
((ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.imageView1)).setImageURI(IMAGE_URI);
            if (((ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.imageView1)).getBackground()== null){
                ((ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.imageView1)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_01); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, it should resolve your issue.

```
   @Override
   public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

       ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView1)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name")));
       ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView2)).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("BirthDate")));
       ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView1)).setTypeface(tf);
       ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.textView2)).setTypeface(tf); 

       String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imageUri"));
       Uri IMAGE_URI= Uri.withAppendedPath(image, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
       Bitmap map = getBitMapfromUri(context,IMAGE_URI.toString(),128,128); // Put your desirable height, whatever you want

       if(map == null){
           // Load your default Image
       }else{
           ((ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(map);
       }

   }

    public  Bitmap getBitMapfromUri(Context context, String uri,
            int width, int height) {

        Bitmap map = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
             is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    Uri.parse(uri));
            Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.inSampleSize = 1;
            opts.inPurgeable = true;
            opts.inInputShareable = true;

            map = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opts), width, height,
                    false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                if(is!=null)
                    is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: Good idea, but its always returning a null bitmap. Forcing the default image on each imageview.

Comment: is it, can you check if uri of thumbnails are correct, am using same code and it works for me, paste a sample uri here

Comment: Yes if I try it without bitmap conversion I have an image in atleast one contact and I can display it using regular code.

Comment: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/675 is a valid image Uri on my phone which translates to a valid bitmap.

Comment: I also tried to toast a message in the if(is!=null) part, but its never printed.

Comment: Hold on i got the issue for null bitmaps, 2 min.

Comment: Uri.withAppendedPath takes an argument of Uri, String. However I changed that, but it still dont work.